# Documentation: List of all callback functions for Office Ribbon controls

Tags: vsto, ribbon, ribbon-control

I am customizing the Office Ribbon in Outlook 2010 but this question probably applies to all Office apps:

I've seen many websites so far that have instructions for setting the text of an editBox using a callback function, or setting the values of a comboBox using a callback function, but no 'universal' reference that has a definitive list of all callback functions with the arguments that .Net will expect to pass to each one. Where is it?!

TIA,
Dave

Comment: Good question! Sure is a lot of crap information out there...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hooray! Looky what I just found!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691833.aspx#odc_Office2010Introduction2OutSpaceUI_DescriptionsAttributesChildInformation